# Return Month and Year Directory Names and Folder Sizes

Tags: php

I have a directory that contains subdirectories of Year (e.g. 2009), and within these sub directories contain sub directories of months (e.g. 02)

I need to calculate the total files in each month folder, along with the total file size for each folder, and out put the two totals (Total Size & Total Files) along with the year and month folder names.

**Example:**

- 05/2009 - 512MB (12 Files)
- 06/2009 - 45KB (21 Files)
- 07/2009 - 6MB (8 Files)
- 01/2011 - 54MB (2 Files)
- 04/2011 - 652MB (55 Files)

...

I have created the following function that will calculate the total size and file of a directory. How do I adapt it to cater for muti sub folders lists as outlined above?

```
function foldersize($path) {
    $total_size = 0;
    $total_files = 0;

    $files = scandir($path);

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if ($t<>"." && $t <> "..") {
            if (is_dir($path.'/'.$file)) {
                $size = foldersize($path.'/'.$file);
                $total_files++;
                $total_size += $size;
            }
            else {
                $size = filesize($path.'/'.$file);
                $total_files++;
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }   
    }

    return $total_size.' | '.$total_files;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `recursiveDirectoryIterator` and `recursiveIteratorIterator` classes provided in SPL.  This should meet your needs quite nicely.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php

Sample usage:

```
$path = realpath('/path/to/directory');
$total_files = 0;
$total_filesize = 0;
$dir_files = 0;
$dir_filesize = 0;

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$first_dir = true;
foreach($iterator as $path => $object){
    if ($path->isDir()) {
        // echo out information from last directory
        if (false === $first_dir) {
            echo "Number of Files in Directory: " . $dir_files . "\nTotal File Size of Directory: " . $dir_filesize . " bytes\n\n";
            // reset directory counters
            $dir_files = 0;
            $dir_filesize = 0;
        }
        // start new directory output
        echo $path->getPathname() . "\n";
    } else if ($path->isFile()) {
        $total_filesize += $path->getSize();
        $dir_filesize += $path->getSize();
        $total_files++;
        $dir_files++;
    }
}

echo "\nTotal Files: " . $total_files . "\nTotal File Size: " . $total_filesize . " bytes";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to iterate over subdirectories recursively.

```
$_recursiveIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $_recursiveIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($iterator as $subdirPath => $subdirInfo) {
    if ($subdirInfo->isDir()) {
        echo $subdirPath . ' ' . foldersize($subdirPath);
    }
}
```

What happens here is a bit difficult to understand and the SPL Iterators are not documented well, so I'll try to explain:

- [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) are objects that implement a special interface so they can
  be used in `foreach` loops
- [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is a recursive iterator for the file system. Recursive iterators are a special type of iterator that yield an iterator themselves in each iteration. They can be used for nested data structures.
- `SKIP_DOTS` tells it to ignore the `.` and `..` entries
- The [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) is used to "flatten" a recursive iterator. It gets passed a recursive iterator and yields all subsequent entries in a single loop.
- `SELF_FIRST` means that parents are yielded before their children (i.e. 2009 before 2009/01)
- in the loop, the key `$subdirPath` is the path of each item and the value `$subdirInfo` a [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) object (in fact, it is the RecursiveDirectoryIterator itself which extends from SplFileInfo in the end - but that doesn't matter at this point)
- isDir() checks if the current item is a directory

The next step would be to refactor your `foldersize()` function to use iterators too. It might be sensible to to the iteration over all files and size calculation at once. *Edit: Look at the answer from Mike Brant for such a solution, the explanation above applies to that too.*

Comment: +1 For nice detailed explanation around the use of the iterators.